# use multiple location geofencing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geofencing, geofence

I used this code

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmAtMqljH9M&list=PLdHg5T0SNpN3GBUmpGqjiKGMcBaRT2A-m&index=9&ab_channel=yoursTRULY)

(https://github.com/trulymittal/Geofencing)

That code makes geofence by click and uses just one geofencing.

But I wanna make geofence one more fixed markers when it start, and use one more geofencing.

So I revised this code(MapsActivity.java) by

```
package com.example.geofencing;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;
    private GeofenceHelper geofenceHelper;

    private float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 20;
    private String GEOFENCE_ID = "SOME_GEOFENCE_ID";

    private int FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;
    private int BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 10002;

    private List<LatLng> latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        geofenceHelper = new GeofenceHelper(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
       
        //move the camera to the starting point
        LatLng latLng_start = new LatLng(37.462749, 126.910311);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng_start, 16));

        latLng = new ArrayList<>();
        latLng.add(new LatLng(38.462349, 123.909955));
        latLng.add(new LatLng(38.463194, 123.911317));
        latLng.add(new LatLng(38.462720, 123.910768));
        latLng.add(new LatLng(38.462743, 123.910317));

        for (LatLng i : latLng) {
            addMarker(i);
            addCircle(i, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
            addGeofence(i, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
        }


//        for (int i = 0; i < markerLocation.length; i++) {
//            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLocation[i][0], markerLocation[i][1]);
//            addMarker(latLng);
//            addCircle(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
//            addGeofence(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
//        }
        enableUserLocation();
    }

    private void enableUserLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Ask for permission
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                //We need to show user a dialog for displaying why the permission is needed and then ask for the permission...
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng latLng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private void addCircle(LatLng latLng, float radius) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.center(latLng);
        circleOptions.radius(radius);
        circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(64, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(4);
        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    }

    private void addGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius) {

        Geofence geofence = geofenceHelper.getGeofence(GEOFENCE_ID, latLng, radius, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geofenceHelper.getGeofencingRequest(geofence);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Geofence Added...");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //We have the permission
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //We do not have the permission..

            }
        }

        if (requestCode == BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //We have the permission
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can add geofences...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //We do not have the permission..
                Toast.makeText(this, "Background location access is neccessary for geofences to trigger...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, when start the app, four markers and Circles(I added fout latLng) are added on the map!

But only the last latLng works geofence function
(LatLng(38.462743, 123.910317), such as alarm when enter the place),

the others doesn't work geofence function.

I want to make the others location works geofencing function well lol

Plz. help me :(

I need a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new Geofencing Request for each LatLng coordinate. Instead, you should create a single Geofencing Request containing a list of all Geofences you want to monitor:

Create a function to build your Geofencing Request:

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    ArrayList<Geofence> geofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Iterate through your LatLng(s) to build the Geofence list
    for(LatLng coordinate: latLngList){

        // Set up each Geofence with your corresponding values
        geofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("My Geofence ID") // A string to identify this geofence
                .setCircularRegion(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, Constants.GEOFENCE_LARGE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .build()
        );
    }
    
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

    // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
    // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
    // is already inside that geofence.
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);

    // Add the geofences to be monitored by geofencing service using the list we created.
    builder.addGeofences(geofenceList);

    return builder.build();
}
```

You should change addGeofence() to look something like this:

```
private void addGeofences() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    
    // Pass the request built with the getGeofencingRequest() function to the Geofencing Client
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), pendingIntent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Geofence Added...");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
                }
            });
}
```

Finally, inside of your onMapReady():

```
latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
latLngList.add(new LatLng(38.462349, 123.909955));
latLngList.add(new LatLng(38.463194, 123.911317));
latLngList.add(new LatLng(38.462720, 123.910768));
latLngList.add(new LatLng(38.462743, 123.910317));

addGeofences(); // Add all of your geofences to the client
```

Comment: I don't know if that means that your issue is solved. If it is, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. If you found a different way to solve your problem, you should create your own answer and accept it in case it helps others with the same problem.